# Content Type not being passed in functional test using sfBrowser in Symfony 1.4

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, functional-testing

The test is for a POST api endpoint where the data is contained in the body of the post as JSON. Prior to making the post call I set the `Content-Type` to `'application/json'`. However, when I test the format `isFormat('JSON')` the response is null. If I dump the `$request->contentType()` this also produces null.

Any reason to why `setHttpHeader('Content-Type','application/json')` is not setting the header correctly during functional testing?

Answer (score 1):

Your setting method is correct, but inside sfBrowserBase there is this bug:

```
foreach ($this->headers as $header => $value)
{
  $_SERVER['HTTP_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-', '_', $header))] = $value;
}
```

that set content_type with prefix HTTP. But in your action $request->getContentType() method suppose that you don't have prefix.

so if you change this:

```
foreach ($this->headers as $header => $value)
{
  $_SERVER[strtoupper(str_replace('-', '_', $header))] = $value;
}
```

you can make `$request->getContentType()` correctly!

You can find update [here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/10081#preview) .

Comment: That actually breaks other headers. You need to put in an exception for ContentType since `$request->getContentType()` is looking for header without HTTP but others such as `$request->isXmlHttpRequest()` does need the HTTP_ prefix.  Therefore the foreach loop becomes: `foreach ($this->headers as $header => value) { if(strtolower($header) == 'content-type' || strtolower($header) == 'content_type') { $_SERVER[strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$header))] = $value; } else { $_SERVER['HTTP_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$header))] = $value; }`

Answer (score 1):

Right thanks to @nicolx I can explain more about what is happening and offer some further guidance.

As noted by @nicolx `$request->getContentType()` is looking for HTTP header without the prefix HTTP_ (see line 163 to 173 in `sfWebRequest`). However, sfBrowserBase always adds HTTP_ prefix to all headers. So add in this mod:

```
foreach($this->headers as $header => $value) 
{
  if(strotolower($header) == 'content-type' || strtolower($header) == 'content_type')
  {
    $_SERVER[strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$header))] = $value;
  } else {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_'.strtoupper(str_replace('-','_',$header))] = $value;
  }
}
```

That will deal with `ContentType` header being set and detectable in your actions. If you don't include the `HTTP_` prefix the other headers won't work (e.g. `$request->isXmlHtttpHeader()` will fail even if you set this in the test file).

The test method `isFormat()` isn't testing the ContentType header but the Symfony route setting [sf_format](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/jobeet/1_4/en/15?orm=Doctrine). If I set the route to specifically have `sf_format: json` e.g.

```
some_route:
  url: /something/to/do
  param: {module: top, action: index, sf_format: json}
```

then the test

```
with('request')->begin()->
   isFormat('json')->
end()->
```

returns true.

As I wanted to test the header settings, I added a new tester method to sfTesterRequest called `isContentType()`. The code for this method is:

```
public function isContentType($type)
{
  $this->tester->is($this->request->getContentType(),$type, sprintf('request method is "%s"',strtoupper($type)));

  return $this->getObjectToReturn();
}
```

Calling this test simply becomes:

```
with('request')->begin()->
  isContentType('Application/Json')->
end()->
```